# Error: error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line when using SSL certificate on Google Cloud?

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-build

I am getting this error when I deploy my docker image with my Node.js app in it to Google Cloud Build:

```
Error: error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line
    at /home/app/node_modules/.pnpm/pg-pool@3.6.1_pg@8.11.3/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:45:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

So that is because I'm doing this with the `pg` postgres pool in Node.js:

```
import pg from 'pg'

const { Pool } = pg

export const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    cert: process.env.DATABASE_SSL_CERT,
  },
})
```

My `DATABASE_SSL_CERT` in my local `.env` file works fine, it is like this:

```
DATABASE_SSL_CERT="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
lines
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
```

When I paste it into the single-line textbox for ENV variables on Google Cloud Build, it appears to remove the newline `\n` characters.

[image]

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Have a look at this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70333915/18265702)  and [Github Link](https://github.com/outline/outline/discussions/3491#discussioncomment-2689872).